# Tableau - double quotations

Tags: tableau-api, startswith

I'm looking to create a field (Abstract) in tableau in which checks if the string has 1 double quotation, or 2 double quotations, or even 3 double quotations

I have the following, is only outputting 1 quotation and No quotations, how can I fix this?

```
If startswith([Abstract], '"') THEN '1 quotations'
ELSEIF startswith([Abstract], '""') THEN '2 quotations'
ELSEIF startswith([Abstract], '"""') THEN '3 quotations'
ELSE 'No quotation'
END
```

Thank you!

Comment: The logic of the statement is wrong. any string starting with two or three quotation marks will *always* start with one quotation mark so the first clause will *always* give the result '1 quotation' for those cases.

Comment: Agreed the comment above. Try using REGEX for this.

Comment: Thank you all - How can I use it with REGEX? @Bernardo

Answer (score 0):

Even though you can rely on REGEX, your formula may work just switching the order of your if/elseif.

Be sure to test the "least common" option first and the the others:

```
IF startswith([Abstract], '"""') THEN '3 quotations'
ELSEIF startswith([Abstract], '""') THEN '2 quotations'
ELSEIF startswith([Abstract], '"') THEN '1 quotation'
ELSE 'No quotation'
END
```